# Oscillations and Spring balances problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring, oscillators

**Problem Statement:**

> A spring balance has a scale that reads from 0 to 50 kg. The length of
>   the scale is  20 cm. A body suspended from this balance, when
>   displaced and released oscillates with a period of 0.6 seconds. What
>   is the weight of the body?

**Question:** I know how to find the frequency of the oscillation from the given data. My concern is how does one figure out the spring constant of this balance? I feel that finding this piece of information is key to solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously want to use Hooke's Law to determine the spring constant.  The problem statement says that a 50 kg mass stretches the spring 0.2 m.  This is enough information to calculate "k" from the equation $F=kx$.

Comment: So, the phrase "length of the scale" actually refers to the maximum extended length of the spring scale?

Comment: I have to say "yes", because if I don't make that assumption, I can't work the problem.

Comment: Or perhaps, the "length of the scale" refers to the length of the spring without any body suspended to it, because the scale itself must have some weight and thus cause some stretching to the spring. Just a different analysis!

Comment: @rnels12, the question is obviously ambiguous.

Comment: @DavidWhite I didn't disagree with you, just offered an alternative interpretation of the question, so the questioner would double checked the question.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that the question is pretty ambiguous too. In fact, I initially interpreted the question much like how rnels12 did. This is why I was unable to solve the problem. I believe @DavidWhite interpretation to be the only way to solve the problem. Thank you!